# How to instantly get Item Counter back to 1000 after power up expires?

Tags: deathsmiles

It's possible in Deathsmiles to somehow position yourself precisely enough so that when the Item Counter expires, you're flooded with a collection of items that instantly restores your counter back to 1000.

I've never been able to pull this off.  The greatest I've ever been able to do is restore it to around 200.

How do you do this?  I've seen it done in many of the leaderboard replay videos.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you kill an enemy that drops A LOT of crowns just before power-up mode ends and pick them up when you are returned to normal mode, you will recharge your counter to 1000 (or close to 1000). This technique involves a lot of practice and timing.

You can also recharge using a bomb. Although it's easier to pull off, it also uses up a good chunk of your power-up time. To do this, release a bomb when your counter is ~400 and hold the lock-shot button. The bomb will kill everything on the screen, grab the crowns only AFTER power-up mode ends.

Take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbM8WVZdRuo).